# model.addAttribute() parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to `Spring MVC` Framework. I'm doing some self study to extend my knowledge in Java.

This is how I understand the `getProducts()` code definition from a tutorial I'm following but please correct me if I'm wrong.

**Controller** requests something from the **Data Access Object** `>`
**Data Access Object** gets the data from a **Database** or a **Model** through the `getProductList()` method `>` Stores the information to list `>` Then binds the list to the model.

So I got two question about this.

Is the inclusion of `model` as parameter in public `String getProducts(Model model)` considered the **dependency injection**

Is `products` (within quotes) in `model.addAttribute("products",products);` just a name which I can change to whatever I like or should it match something?

```
public class HomeController {

    private ProductDao productDao = new ProductDao();

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/productList")
    public String getProducts(Model model){
        List<Product> products = productDao.getProductList();
        model.addAttribute("products",products);

        return "productList";  //productList string is the productList.jsp which is a view
    }

    @RequestMapping("/productList/viewProduct")
    public String viewProduct(){
        return "viewProduct";
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any explanation or comment.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is only a name, which will be used, to get the value in the jsp

Comment: products (within quotes) in model.addAttribute("products",products);  should match it's surrogate in the view (jsp for example.) !! It doesnt have to match the List<Product> products. you can change to whatever you like as long as it matches its jsp's surrogate .

Answer (score 8):

Yes,
model is instantiated by spring and injected to your method, means if any of model attribute matches anything in request it will be filled. and it should be the last param in the method

```
model.addAttribute("products",products);
```

"products" is just a name which you can use it in your view get the value with `${products}`

Answer (score 0):

My code. this is sample.

```
    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/settings/product")
    public ModelAndView showProduct(ModelAndView mav, HttpServletRequest req, Authentication auth) {
        CustomUserDetail customUserDetail = (CustomUserDetail) auth.getPrincipal();

        int associationIdx = customUserDetail.getAccount().getAssociation().getIdx();

        String language = CookieUtil.getCookieValue(req, "lang");

        Association association = associationService.findAssociationByIdx(associationIdx);

        List<AssociationProductColumnDefine> columns = associationService.findByAssociationAndLanguage(association,
                language);
        List<AssociationProductColumnDefine> source = associationService.findByAssociationAndLanguage(association,
                "ko-kr");

        mav.addObject("association", association);
        mav.addObject("source", source);
        mav.addObject("columns", columns);

        mav.setViewName("/association/association_settings_product");

        return mav;
    }
```

1. Yes, you choice model and ModelAndView.
2. Yes, simple.